# session is not working in new server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, server

I moved my code-igniter project to new server but session is not working across other page but in same page controller function is like

```
public function login()
{
    $typo = "teacher";
    $co=array('ededge_typo' => $typo);
    $this->session->set_userdata($co);
    $this->load->view('header');
}
```

in view

```
<?php var_dump($this->session->userdata('ededge_typo'))); ?>
```

but i get output Null

when i tried in localhost i get

```
C:\wamp\www\cii\application\views\header.php:1:string 'Teacher' (length=7)
```

please help me to

my configuration in codeigniter is

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

Comment: $config['sess_save_path']  should be a directory on the server (tmp folder?) if you are using sess_driver == 'files'.  
Make that directory writeable with ssh/ftp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print session by print_r($_SESSION) on your view page. Print it, if your session is set it will show you.

Comment: now i get this array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1483702885) }

Comment: In your controller have you added the session library.check it.like this $this->load->library('session');

Comment: auto loaded it autoload.php

Comment: add this $this->load->library('session'); in your controller and then check.

Comment: after adding this have you login again and then check. 
after that if not then try to check by session_start(), 
$_SESSION['ededge_typo']=$typo;
and print session on view file

Answer (score 0):

Use database session

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks.

Comment: i got error session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: /tmp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/var/www/html/my_app/tmp/';
```

From codeigniter documentation:

> 'sess_save_path'
>   |
>   |   The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
>   |
>   |   For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
>   |   WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
>   |
>   |   For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
>   |   Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
>   |
>   |   IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!

If you dont want to change that folder manually every time when you change server, you could try something like

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'tmp/';
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'tmp/';
```

The fcpath one should be xxx/my_app/tmp
and basepath should be xxx/my_app/application/tmp

Both folders should be writeable.

Comment: BASEPATH . 'tmp/'; i get same result

Comment: it seems to be server problem